# Get output from Foreach equal to result from for loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, parallel-foreach, nested-for-loop

I am currently turning a `for` loop into a `foreach` loop so I can parallelize the calculations of the inner loop. I am able to do that and get the correct output. However, I want the format of the output from `foreach` to be equal to the format I had in my old `for` loop. Here's a reproducible example to what I want to do:

FOR LOOP:

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(5)
z <- c(3)

result_list <- list()
for(i in length(x)){
        for(j in 1:y){
                for(k in 1:z){
                        
                result <- rnorm(n = 250)
                result_list[[paste(i, j, k)]] <- result
                }
        }
}
```

That's the output I get and what I want to achieve:

```
library(dplyr)
glimpse(result_list)
List of 15
 $ 10 1 1: num [1:250] -0.382 -0.156 -0.747 1.139 -1.824 ...
 $ 10 1 2: num [1:250] -0.181 0.526 0.255 -0.369 -1.517 ...
 $ 10 1 3: num [1:250] 0.3621 1.3634 -0.0507 -0.3943 -1.2183 ...
 $ 10 2 1: num [1:250] -1.453 0.731 2.761 -0.586 -1.631 ...
 $ 10 2 2: num [1:250] -0.663 -0.641 -1.852 1.58 0.133 ...
 $ 10 2 3: num [1:250] -1.334 0.803 -0.116 0.618 -1.339 ...
 $ 10 3 1: num [1:250] 0.158 -1.296 -0.947 -0.515 -0.208 ...
 $ 10 3 2: num [1:250] -0.604 1.956 0.127 1.846 -0.549 ...
 $ 10 3 3: num [1:250] 0.365 -0.467 -0.589 -1.251 0.491 ...
 $ 10 4 1: num [1:250] -1.138 0.883 1 0.729 -1.566 ...
 $ 10 4 2: num [1:250] -0.0461 2.3096 -1.5347 0.3722 0.3125 ...
 $ 10 4 3: num [1:250] 0.127 -0.728 0.402 1.783 -1.457 ...
 $ 10 5 1: num [1:250] 1.855 2.224 1.301 0.166 -0.28 ...
 $ 10 5 2: num [1:250] 0.463 -1.011 1.067 -1.305 -0.51 ...
 $ 10 5 3: num [1:250] 1.937 0.651 -0.424 -0.714 -0.225 ...
```

That's the code to the FOREACH LOOP:

```
library(foreach)
result_list <- list()
resultado_foreach <- foreach::foreach(i = 1:10, .inorder = TRUE) %do% {
        
                foreach::foreach(j = 1:5, .inorder = TRUE) %do% {
                        foreach::foreach((k = 1:3)) %dopar% {
                                
                                result <- rnorm(n = 250)
                                result_list[[paste(i, j, k)]] <- result
                                
                        }
                
        }
}
```

Although, I get a list of lists of lists (a nested-nested list):

```
glimpse(resultado_foreach)
List of 10
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] 0.911 0.594 -0.453 0.651 2.303 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] -0.664 -0.696 0.741 -2.78 -0.992 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] -0.6877 -1.1266 -1.7784 0.473 0.0185 ...
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] 1.273 0.129 0.902 2.47 0.177 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] 0.705 0.519 1.219 -1.682 -0.355 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] 1.138 0.422 -1.025 -0.237 0.418 ...
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] -1.636 -1.297 -1.115 -0.138 0.174 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] 0.56 -1.311 0.641 0.861 -0.601 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] 0.198 -1.197 0.781 -0.571 -0.141 ...
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] -0.355 -0.649 -1.046 -0.717 -0.97 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] -1.086 0.912 -0.996 0.303 1.418 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] 0.8827 -0.0761 1.3504 -0.5301 0.2267 ...
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] -1.826 1.286 1.585 -0.359 -0.955 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] -0.588 -0.314 -0.223 -0.779 0.569 ...
  .. ..$ : num [1:250] 1.047 -0.242 -0.345 0.27 -0.158 ...
```

The `foreach` output is much longer than what I have put here.

I have already tried many combinations and set many functions to the `.combine` argument in the `foreach` function. So, how can I obtain the output in the same format of the `for loop`?

Comment: You could just use 'unlist'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in your for loop you have

```
for(i in length(x)) {...}
```

but `length(x)` is 10 so you are just doing `for(i in 10)` which only loops once. That's not the same as `for (i in 1:10)`. A safer alternative is `for (i in seq_along(x))`.

So let's say that you expect 10 outer loops, each with 5 middle loops, and each with 3 inner loops. That should be 10x5x3 = 150 total results.

If you want to use nested loops with for each, you should use the `%:%` operator. Plus you'll also want to use `.combine=c` to concatenate the inner loops into a single list at the end. These options are discussed on the `?foreach` help page.

A better version would be

```
resultado_foreach <- 
  foreach::foreach(i = 1:10, .inorder = TRUE, .combine=c) %:%
    foreach::foreach(j = 1:5, .inorder = TRUE, .combine=c) %:% 
      foreach::foreach((k = 1:3)) %dopar% {
        rnorm(n = 250)
      }
```

This will return a list of length 150 each with a vector of length 250.
Note that you shouldn't modify global variables when using `foreach`. Each block should return a value and `foreach` will collect and combine those values for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I tried to make a more general example with my code and it did not work for my specif case. @MrFlick, can I erase my question and ask again?

Comment: You can delete your own question and post a new one. But please make sure that your example reflects what you are trying to do so no additional effort is spent on solving problems that don't actually need solving.

Comment: I won't erase my question because, even though, your answer helped me! Is solved 95% of my problem. Now I have another one! Thank you so much! I'll tag this as solved.